# Naming Laravel view routes when using resource routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes

## Problem

I have been struggling all day to find a good convention to **name view routes** in **Laravel (5.4)**. 

Let's say that I am using resource routes. But I also need to declare a lot of view routes, what is a safe and best **practice** for declaring such routes?

## Example:

**I have the following resource routes:**

```
GET /tickets/12/messages
GET /tickets/12/messages/5
POST /tickets/12/messages
PUT /tickets/12/messages/5
PATCH /tickets/12/messages/5
DELETE /tickets/12/messages/5
```

I also need to define routes for:

- Displaying the view to edit a particular message.
- Displaying the view to add a particular message to a ticket.
- Displaying the view to create a particular ticket.
- Displaying the view to show all the tickets in the system.
- Displaying the view to show all the tickets that belong to a particular user.

And many others... The question is: **How would you define the routes I described?**

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Laravel way to build routes for CRUD is to use the `Route::resource()` method:

```
Route::resource('tickets', 'TicketController');
```

You can see a list of generated routes with `php artisan route:list` command.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: Alright, sir, let's say I use the Route::resource method. Could you suggest a robust naming convention for the routes that simply return views?

Comment: @NelutuFona `resource()` will name all created routes for you. You can see route names in the list generated with `php artisan route:list` command. Or click the link in my answer, there is a table there that shows route names Laravel uses for CRUD.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO you can try to use nested resources, in your case:

```
Route::resource('tickets.messages', 'TicketMessageController');
Route::resource('users.tickets', 'UserTicketController');
```

they generate this kind of routes:

```
tickets/{ticket}/messages/{message} 
users/{user}/tickets/{ticket}
```

In the controller you will have both parameters injected in function calls, i.e.:

```
class TicketMessageController

// show message for ticket
public function show(Ticket $ticket, Message $message)

// show all messages for a ticket
public function index(Ticket $ticket)
```

Its [documented](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-nested-resources) only for Laravel 5.1 but it works with 5.4

As always you can review all the generated routes with `php artisan route:list`